# Memory leak - any guesses where it can be

Tags: c#, wcf, nhibernate, automapper-2

I'm working on .Net project (windows service) and I found memory leak. Using ANTS Memory profiler, I've determined - root cause is in unmanaged memory scope. But I don't use any COM/COM+ or p/invoke - pure .Net (DataAcces - Fluent nHibernate, Automapper, WCF)..

Hypothetically, what can be reason? How can I find bottleneck.. I'm interested in any kind of experience, who've faced and solved such kind of isseus

A bit more details:

- I know how objects are disposing (and do it right)
- I (almost) don't use events
- I'm using timers
- I'm using multithreading (but it's rather parallelism)
- My application is not stateless - I'm tracking objects during their life-cycle

Comment: I wasn't aware you could get a memory leak with C#. Isn't it all about garbage collection? Are you using unsafe code?

Comment: @dotTutorials GC only goes so far, but yes, you can create memory leaks.

Comment: You most certainly can, Microsoft messaging on this is just bad for educating developers.

Comment: You should use memory profiler.

Comment: According ANTS memory profiler, managed heap was ok - I've got increasing unmanaged memory

Comment: @meziantou - like the one from ANTS ?

Comment: Alone context on what your service does would be helpful. Can you identify a ball-park phase in the app where you think this could be occurring?

Comment: Yes, I have some thinks where it can be occur. Unfortunately (for my project) I'm currently on vacation, but as far as it's ends I'll provide results of my investigation as a one more memory leak possible case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### About Memory Leaks

Generally Speaking Memory Leaks still can exist in .net. (Sort of, not all of these are text book memory leaks per se) As in things get stuck in generation 2 garbage collection or when not disposing of object that inherit from IDisposable or for that matter Streams, Events, SQL connections that stay open and mess with you connection pool.While I am not an expert in the matter I will point you to a couple of places that may help you on your quest.

- [Memory Management Fundementals](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/learning-memory-management/memory-management-fundamentals?utm_source=reflector&utm_medium=blog&utm_content=rickyleeks5&utm_campaign=antsmemoryprofiler)
- [Detecting Memory Leaks in .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42721/Best-Practices-No-5-Detecting-NET-application-memo#Introduction)

While you are at it Groking the way that garbage collection works helps in this sort of endevor a great deal. Start with something like [The Fundementals of Garbage Collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088.aspx) for a general mental picture of just what the heck is going on with all that .NET magic behind the scenes.

### On the COM Stuff

Inherent in .NET there are many things that are just simply com and or win32 wrappers calling PInvoke behind the scenes. If gettin down and dirty with insides is what you are wanting then I'd recommend you look at a Decompiler (like IL Spy) where you suspect the leaky code.

Check this out for a deeper discussion on all the wrapper related stuff. 
[Is .NET A Wrapper Around Win32?](http://www.grimes.nildram.co.uk/dotnet/dotnetWrappers.htm)